# Web Service Client could not connect to the server

Tags: java, web-services, https, glassfish

I have created Web Service, which work on Glassfish 3.1.1 with https, when I try to connect to web service there are errors.
Trace:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:194)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:95)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:146)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
at $Proxy32.getGUIDE(Unknown Source)
at webserviceclient.WebServiceClient.getGUIDE(WebServiceClient.java:56)
at webserviceclient.WebServiceClient.main(WebServiceClient.java:38)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:430)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:428)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:427)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:468)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:974)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:105)
```

Errors in server.log, when I try in browser "?Tester"

```
[#|2012-10-03T15:38:24.250+0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=418;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|parsing WSDL...

|#]

[#|2012-10-03T15:38:24.359+0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=418;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[ERROR] java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Failed to read the WSDL document: https://192.168.40.2/WebService/NSI_NBRK?WSDL, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.|#]

[#|2012-10-03T15:38:24.359+0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=418;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|[ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): 

 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.|#]

[#|2012-10-03T15:38:24.360+0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=418;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|  Failed to parse the WSDL.|#]

[#|2012-10-03T15:38:24.360+0600|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.webservices.org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring|_ThreadID=418;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Invoking wsimport with https://192.168.40.2/WebService/NSI_NBRK?WSDL|#]
[#|2012-10-03T15:38:24.361+0600|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.webservices.org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring|_ThreadID=418;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|wsimport failed|#]
```

wsdl:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://service/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://service/" name="NSI_NBRK">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://service/" schemaLocation="./NSI_NBRK.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="GET_GUIDE">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:GET_GUIDE"/>
</message>
<message name="GET_GUIDEResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:GET_GUIDEResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="Service">
<operation name="GET_GUIDE">
<input wsam:Action="http://service/Service/GET_GUIDERequest" message="tns:GET_GUIDE"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://service/Service/GET_GUIDEResponse" message="tns:GET_GUIDEResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="ServicePortBinding" type="tns:Service">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="GET_GUIDE">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="NSI_NBRK">
<port name="ServicePort" binding="tns:ServicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="https://192.168.40.2/WebService/NSI_NBRK"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

and xsd schema:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.1.1-b09 (branches/2.1-6834; 2011-07-16T17:14:48+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.5-promoted-b04 JAXWS/2.2. --><xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://service/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://service/">

<xs:element name="GET_GUIDE" type="tns:GET_GUIDE"/>

<xs:element name="GET_GUIDEResponse" type="tns:GET_GUIDEResponse"/>

<xs:complexType name="GET_GUIDE">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arg0" type="tns:serviceRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="serviceRequest">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="beginDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="endDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="guideCode" type="tns:guideCode" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="type" type="tns:guideType" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GET_GUIDEResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="return" type="tns:serviceResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="serviceResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="errCode" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="errMsg" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="result" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="guideCode">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="NSI_NBRK_BANK"/>
<xs:enumeration value="NSI_NBRK_CRCY_COURSE"/>
<xs:enumeration value="NSI_NBRK_KNP"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="guideType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="FULL"/>
<xs:enumeration value="CHAD"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And also web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>300</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>service</web-resource-name>
            <description>service</description>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <description>service</description>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Comment: A ConnectException typically gets thrown when you try to connect to an address where no one is listening. Are you sure the service is running? Moreover, please post the full WSDL and XSD, only the meta tag and a comment isn't particularily helpful.

Comment: I check connection with a browser, it shows me a wsdl and schema, but when I try "?Tester" it gives me an error "Error generating artifacts for the following WSDL https://192.168.40.2/WebService/NSI_NBRK?WSDL

Possible causes can be invoking https when the application is not configured for security"

Comment: How did you configure the service to use https? I can see the WS-Security and WS-Policy namespace definitions in your WSDL, but there is no actual policy.

Comment: I updated the question with web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is connectivity issue. try to see the wsdl from a web browser to check the connectivity or just do a pin to 192.168.40.2

What is the exception you are getting.

Check this url whether it helps to you?

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Comment: ping to 192.168.40.2 is OK, and I can get wsdl from browser

Comment: Check this url whether it helps to you?

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/

Comment: He is using glassfish. I doubt that a tomcat tutorial will help.

Comment: I've added certificate to the keystore before, and did not help.

Comment: The problem solved by explicitly adding arguments to client application -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore and -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword. Thanks to all for responding!